# How to create olap user in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to build Olap. While building an error has been occurred. First of all, I downloaded olaptrain schema, then I opened a command prompt on the olaptrain folder, then I logged on sqlplus with sysdba. After that, when I Write "@Install_olaptrain", I got an error "ORA-01919 role Olap_User Not Exist". What is the source of error? How can we create that role? [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EbA9.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, creating a role is a simple task:

```
create role olap_user;
```

but I'm not sure it is the way to go. I'd expect the script to contain *all* info it needs to complete successfully (which includes the abovementioned `create role`). Anyway: create it, it won't do any harm, but might help.